# Python 3.5 Pandas import error

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python 3.5 on my Mac Book Pro. I installed pandas using 
`pip3 install pandas` If I open `ipython` and run 
`import pandas as pd` I get the following error.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
      6 try:
----> 7     from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
      8 except ImportError as e:  # pragma: no cover

ImportError: cannot import name 'hashtable'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-af55e7023913> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     11                       "pandas from the source directory, you may need to run "
     12                       "'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C "
---> 13                       "extensions first.".format(module))
     14 
     15 from datetime import datetime

ImportError: C extension: 'hashtable' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

Comment: Did the `pip3 install pandas` give any error messages?

Comment: Use Anaconda. Actually, install Miniconda, and run `conda install pandas`. Your peace of mind is very important to them at Continnum.io.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says

```
If you want to import pandas from the source directory,
you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

Have you tried running that at

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/
```

Or any places else that contain a `setup.py` for `Pandas`?

Answer (score 0):

try to run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` here `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/` to build the C extensions of pandas

Comment: can't find `setup.py` in pandas or anywhere else.

Comment: make sure you've installed Xcode and **command line tools for XCode** then try to reinstall it pandas. and if still didn't work try to run the command I said above

Comment: how do do that on Mac Book ?

Comment: you can find a complete guide to installation here
http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html

Comment: still doesn't help and can't find setup.py. I did try locate after building the database.

Comment: are you sure you've installed Xcode and command line tools for Xcode and the reinstalled the panads again and still have problem?